# What are the kung fu or wuxia films featured in the training montage in Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles: Mutant Mayhem?

Tags: story-identification, movie, teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles, tmnt-mutant-mayhem

[*Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles: Mutant Mayhem*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8589698/reference/) (2023) shows Splinter and the Ninja Turtles learning ninjutsu by imitating scenes from classic kung fu or wuxia films. Which films are featured in their training montage?

Screenshots and clips of the films featured:

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

The [fourth image (GIF)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8pRq.gif) looks like Jackie Chan in blue on the left, who is also the voice actor for Splinter in this film:

[image: Possibly Jackie Chan?]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've posted a total of twelve images, including the gifs. For the sake of simplicity, let's call them all images and assume they're numbered 1-12 in the order that you posted them.

Image 1 is from ***[The 36th Chamber of Shaolin](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078243/)*** (1978).

> 

Images 2 and 3 are from ***[The Magnificent Ruffians](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079043/)*** (1979).

> 

Images 4, 5, 6, 10, 11 and 12, plus the backflip sequence in image 8, are from ***[Mad Monkey Kung Fu](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079147/)*** (1979). The man in blue in those images isn't Jackie Chan; it's [Chia-Liang Liu](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0514906/?ref_=tt_cl_t_1), also known as Lau Kar-leung. He starred alongside Jackie Chan in *[Drunken Master II](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111512/)* (1994), also known as *The Legend of Drunken Master*.

> 

Image 7 is from ***[Lion vs. Lion](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083002/)*** (1981).

> 

The man in the white T-shirt in images 8 and 9 is Jackie Chan in ***[Snake Fist Fighter](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068000/)*** (1973), his first starring role.

> 

*Snake Fist Fighter* is the only one of these that wasn't released by [Shaw Brothers Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaw_Brothers_Studio).